# SwiftUI makes UIViewRepresentable flicker while updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am rewriting the existing UIKit cell with SwiftUI. `ChartView` inside of it I wrapped with `UIViewRepresentable` because it is out of scope right now to rewrite it as well. The data for the chart I am getting async and update the view once I have it. The viewModel for the chart I marked as @Published so SwiftUI knows when to update the view. The problem is the view flickers once the update is there.

View:

```
struct DashboardWatchlistView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DashboardWatchlistViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            ZStack {
                HStack(spacing: 4) {
                    HStack(spacing: 16) {
                        Image(systemName: "person")

                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .designSystem(8) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(viewModel.leftTitle).font(.subheadline).fontWeight(.semibold).lineLimit(1)
                            }
                            Text(viewModel.leftSubtitle).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(Color(ThemeManager.current.neutral50))
                        }
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    if let chartViewModel = viewModel.chartViewModel {
                        AssetLineChartViewRepresentable(viewModel: chartViewModel).frame(width: 65, height: 20)
                    }

                    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: .designSystem(.extraSmall3)) {
                        percentChangeView(assetPercentChangeType: viewModel.assetPercentChangeType)
                        Text(viewModel.rightSubtitle).font(.caption2).foregroundColor(Color(ThemeManager.current.neutral50))
                    }.padding(.leading, .designSystem(.medium))
                }

                .padding([.leading, .trailing])

                if !viewModel.hideSeparator {
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Divider().padding(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
final class DashboardWatchlistViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var logoURL: URL?
    @Published var leftTitle = ""
    @Published var leftSubtitle = ""
    @Published var rightTitle = ""
    @Published var rightSubtitle = ""
    @Published var percentageChange: Decimal = .zero
    @Published var placeholderColor = ""
    @Published var corners: Corners = .none
    @Published var assetPercentChangeType: AssetPercentChangeType = .zero
    @Published var hideSeparator = false
    @Published var isHighlighted = false
    @Published var chartViewModel: AssetLineChartViewRepresentable.ViewModel?

    let chartDataEvent: AnyPublisher<BPChartData?, Never>

    init(tradable: Tradable,
         priceString: String,
         percentageChange: Decimal,
         corners: Corners,
         hideSeparator: Bool,
         assetPercentChangeType: AssetPercentChangeType,
         chartDataEvent: AnyPublisher<BPChartData?, Never>) {
             self.logoURL = tradable.logoURL
             self.leftTitle = tradable.name
             self.rightTitle = PercentageFormatter.default.string(from: abs(percentageChange))
             self.leftSubtitle = tradable.symbol
             self.rightSubtitle = priceString
             self.percentageChange = percentageChange
             self.placeholderColor = tradable.placeholderColor ?? ""
             self.corners = corners
             self.chartDataEvent = chartDataEvent
             self.hideSeparator = hideSeparator
             self.assetPercentChangeType = assetPercentChangeType
    }
}
```

`Cell` where I set the `chartViewModel`:

```
final class DashboardWatchlistCell: UICollectionViewCell, HostingCell {

    var hostingController: UIHostingController<DashboardWatchlistView>?
    private var dashboardWatchlistView: DashboardWatchlistView?
    private var viewModel: DashboardWatchlistViewModel?

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            viewModel?.isHighlighted = isHighlighted
        }
    }

    func configure(with viewModel: DashboardWatchlistViewModel) {
        self.dashboardWatchlistView = DashboardWatchlistView(viewModel: viewModel)
        self.viewModel = viewModel

        // HERE I SET THE VIEWMODEL
        viewModel.chartDataEvent.compactMap { $0 }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { chartData in
            viewModel.chartViewModel = AssetLineChartViewRepresentable.ViewModel(chartData: chartData, percentageChange: viewModel.percentageChange)
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    func addHostedView(to parent: UIViewController) {
        guard let dashboardWatchlistView = dashboardWatchlistView else { return }

        addHostedView(dashboardWatchlistView, to: parent)

        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is difficult to help without one, but I suspect the flickering problem is due to this code: `if let chartViewModel = viewModel.chartViewModel' See [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/), but every time that is evaluated you are creating a new `UIViewRepresentable`, hence the flicker.

Comment: no, I recreate only the model. and since it is @Published the view gets updated

Comment: Yes it does. Every single time, and because the way you have structured the code, the view gets updated multiple times whether it needs it or not because its identity has changed. Therefore, SwiftUI can't tell if it is the same or a different view and redraws it when it is not necessary, causing the flicker. Please watch Demystify SwiftUI.

Comment: I do not see any other way to let SwiftUI know the model has updated. Worked fine in UIKit

Comment: PLEASE WATCH Demystify SwiftUI. Apple tells you in about 25 minutes how ALL of this works.

Comment: @Yrb you are right regarding recreating the view. But which option do I have if I am getting new data from the server and need to represent it? That is a built-in feature of SwiftUI to recreate a view once some data changes

Comment: You are missing the point. The problem isn't the publishing of the variable. The problem is the If conditional in the SwiftUI view. Either change the view to handle the optional, or pass it as a non-optional. But every time the If conditional gets evaluated, the ID of the view changes, so it is refreshed.